# php variables no value

Tags: php, html

I have striped down the following code to the minimum for clarity
html

```
<form  action="insert.php" method="post">
 <textarea  name="ff1" disabled="disabled">Monday 11 february</textarea>
 <textarea  name="ff2" disabled="disabled" >Selected Match is</textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit Bet" >
 </form>
```

php

```
 <?php

   $myvarA = $_POST['ff1'];
   $myvarB = $_POST['ff2'];
   $sql="INSERT INTO bestmatch (ddate, mmatch)
   VALUES ('$myvarA','$myvarB')";
```

?>

I cannot get  anything into the variables, if I change the following

```
 VALUES ('$myvarA','$myvarB')";
```

to

```
 VALUES ('anytext','anytext2')";
```

then everything is fine, and anytext is entered into my database, so there is no problem connection wise.
I am puzzled as to why the variables will not work

Comment: Try doing `print_r($_POST)` and your error will probably be made pretty apparent. Also, you should be using prepared statements to insert any user-supplied values into your database. Blindly inserting them like that is just asking for your site to be hacked.

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Show more code: How are you executing your (most insecure) query? Are you testing `if (isset($_POST['ff1']))` at any given time?

Comment: It's a blessing for you that it doesn't work. Don't do that, lest you open yourself wide open to trivial injection attacks. Use PDO or `mysqli_` with prepared statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have these fields `disabled` in your form. If you want to hide them from user - just make them `hidden`

Answer (score -2):

Disabled values can never be get in form submit.

Comment: -1 for stealing from the other answer. You can't blame concurrency - you've edited and undeleted your answer _after_ the other one was posted.